# How to read a bitmap file and crop it afterwards?

Tags: python, windows, bitmap

I want to read a bitmap that represents a sprite, and crop a part of it.
Here is an example of an image.

[image: An example]

In Matlab I would have done somethings like:

```
i = imread('myfile.png')
x1 = i(1:64,1:64,:)
```

How can I do the same in python?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[PIL](http://www.pythonware.com/library/pil/handbook/index.htm) could do that, `crop` function in particular.

```
from PIL import Image

img = Image.open(r'yRc2a.png')
img = img.convert('RGBA')
img = img.crop((0, 0, 82, 82))
img.save(r'out.png')
```

I'm not sure, seems like your image uses palette? I added `convert` to RGBA call so output file has transparency. Without `convert` file has green (why green?) color on transparent pixels.